# How to get the Created By and Current Logged In user in itemcheckedin event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I need to get the Created By and Current Logged-In user in my ItemCheckedIn event receiver. Is there any way I can access values.

Comment: Have you looked into `BeforeProperties` & `AfterProperties`? Current logged in user should be fetchable from the `properties.Web.CurrentUser`.